# Closed graph theorem seems to state that a closed operator has to be bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, closed-graph

By the closed graph theorem an operator $T$ is continuous  (equivalently bounded) if and only if it its graph is closed. An operator with a closed graph is called a closed operator.

So we have

$$
T \ \text{bounded} \Longleftrightarrow T \ \text{continuous} \Longleftrightarrow T \ \text{has closed graph} \Longleftrightarrow T \ \text{closed}. \quad (*)
$$

But I often see closed operators mentioned in the context of unbounded operators. That is unbounded operators can be closed. But in $(*)$ above it seems that a closed operator is equivalent to a bounded operator?

Comment: The operator in the closed graph theorem is defined on a Banach. Unbounded closed operators are only defined on a dense subset of a Banach. You can always extend them linearly to the whole space. Then, you can deduce from the closed graph theorem, that there is no way to extend a closed unbounded operator to the whole space while keeping its graph closed.

Comment: @scentofthetrees You should post that as an Answer, for the benefit of future readers. (Heh, if you do please say "a Banach space" instead of "a Banach"...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since in conferences I say "a Banach" and everyone understands, I will keep using it.

Comment: @scentofthetrees Have you ever had an editor let you get away with "a Banach" in a publication? Just curious...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is not a publication, just an internet forum, and you are certainly not my editor.

Comment: That said, in vast swathes of functional analysis, you absolutely have to mind your Banach spaces and Banach algebras…

Comment: @scentofthetrees : It helps the site to show that questions get answered.  I suggest that you paste your answer. I'll +1 it if you do. It's a good, clean answer.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić : Just not in this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T : X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$. Then the closed graph theorem states that the following are equivalent

- $T$ is continuous;
- $T$ is bounded;
- $T$ is closed.

A linear operator $T : \mathcal{D}(T)\subsetneq X\rightarrow Y$ on a linear, dense domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of the closed graph theorem. So $T$ can be closed without being continuous. An example is the differentiation operator $T : C^1[0,1]\subset C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$. This operator is linear, densely-defined and closed, but is not bounded.